# Значения переменных вывода товара minishop2 modx revo 2.2.10

Tags: php, modx, minishop2

На сайте хочу вывести параметры товара на англ. языке. В чанке minishop2 (ms.Product.content) они выводятся через имя записи в словаре. Например:

```
<div class="form-group"><label class="col-sm-2 control-label">[[%ms2_product_article]]:</label>
```

Подскажите, что сделать, чтобы при переключении контекста, например, с русского на английский, эта переменная меняла текст на английский тоже?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

```
[[%ms2_product_article&language=`en`]]
```

Естественно в словаре должен быть соответсвующий перевод данной записи. Читайте внимательнее [доки](https://rtfm.modx.com/revolution/2.x/developing-in-modx/advanced-development/internationalization).